# Regex to replace http AND https links

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following `preg_replace()` function targeting links:

```
$link = preg_replace(
    "#http://([\S]+?)#Uis", '<a href="http://\\1">(link)</a>', 
    $link
);
```

It works fine with `http` links *but* obviously not with `https` links. How can I adjust it so that it works with `https` links as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `s?` after `http` and match the whole link, then use the `$0` backreference to refer to it from the replacement pattern:

```
$link = preg_replace(
    "#https?://\S+#i", '<a href="$0">(link)</a>', 
    $link
);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/zBcbFj)

**Details**:

- `https?` - either `http` or `https`
- `://` - a literal char sequence
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace symbols
- `i` - a case insensitive modifier.

Note the `U` modifier is confusing (`?` would be written as `??`, and the pattern becomes longer), and I suggest removing it.

The `s` modifier does not make sense if the pattern has no `.` in it, so it is also redundant, I suggest removing it, too.

Comment: Pretty much everything I've learned from regex is via your answers here. Thank you so very much. I have one question. Is there any way to adjust the regex in a way where it identifies the URL part properly. For example, the following `$link = 'hello http://example.com) world';` will add the `)` part in the URL if you get my point.

Comment: Why not use `<a href="$0">(link)</a>` in the replacement?

Comment: I thought it was necessary to keep the original capture. Right, perhaps, it is no longer needed.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, you can use a negated character class instead of `\S` to escape the characters you don't want to match. For example `[^\s\)]`