# How to change user input into a link?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

input

```
<div class ="box">
<div class="textbox">
    <label>Job Name</label>&nbsp;
    <input type ="text" class="text" name ="jobname" class="sup">

    <br><label>Time</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type ="text" class="text" name ="jobtime">

    <br><label>Day</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type ="date" class="text" name ="jobday">

    <br><label>Venue</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type ="text" class="text" name ="venue">
    
    <br><label>No. Of Worker</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select id="worker" name="worker">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>

    <br><label>Phone Number</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label>+601</label> <input type ="text" class="phone" name ="phonenum">

    <br><label>Job Scope</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <textarea id="inform" rows="2" cols="19" name ="inform"></textarea>


</div>
```

output

```
<?php
    include("DB.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM createjob";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $id = $row["id"];
                $jobname = $row["jobname"];
                $jobtime = $row["jobtime"];
                $jobday = $row["jobday"];
                $venue = $row["venue"];
                $worker = $row["worker"];
                $inform = $row["inform"];
                $phonenum = $row["phonenum"];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $jobname ; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $jobtime; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $jobday; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $venue; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $worker; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo nl2br($inform);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $phonenum; ?></td>
                    <td><button><a href="apply.php">Apply</a>
                </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }else { 
        echo "0 results";
        
    }
    ?>
```

Based on the code above, I have tried to change the `<td><?php echo nl2br($inform);?></td>` to a link but I failed to do so. So what I want to do is that whatever users insert in the `inform` text-area it will change the user's input to a link.

Comment: what do you mean by 'to a link'? Do you want to hyperlink the user input o do you want to add user input to the URL and pass it to backend code(to send user input via URL)

Comment: What i mean is, if users insert a hyperlink such as google form link or any other website links, the output/display will also be a hyperlink. I am sorry for the wrong explanation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you want to replace URLs (e.g. `https://example.com/`) within the `$inform` variable to be rendered as HTML anchors (e.g. `<a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a>`).

If so, you could have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929564/regex-to-replace-http-and-https-links).

For your example it should be a simple replacement of

```php
$inform = $row["inform"];
```

with the following code:

```php
$inform = preg_replace(
    "#https?://\S+#i", '<a href="$0">$0</a>', 
    $row["inform"]
);
```

> However, reflecting user input without any form of validation,
> sanitization or output encoding is a potential security issue! Please
> consider reading the article from [OWASP about XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) first.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation !! I'll give it a try and consider what have you told me. Thanks again !

Comment: If it works, you can mark the answer as correct which makes it easier for others to find the same solution. If I didn't understand your issue, please let me know so I can update my answer ;)

Comment: I am really sorry but i have found a different answer for my question. Thank you so much though and you guys awesome !!